# How to show and edit the only record from join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are three models User, SearchOption, Search.

```
User has_many :searches, through: :search_options
Search has_many :users, through: :search_options
```

I need to give possibility to adjust search results trough SearchOptions editing. The user should see only his options, but if I do something like that:

```
<%= f.fields_for :search_option do |ff| %>
```

it gives me all options of the search. Actually I did it with one more instance variable `@searchoption = SearchOption.where(user_id: USER.ID, search_id: SEARCH.ID)` but I don't like this way.

How to make output of just one join model record?

**Update**
Here is some more ugly code:
form

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
        <%= f.label 'Projects' %>
          <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:project_ids, current_user.projects.regular_projects, :id, :title) do |b| %>
                <%= b.check_box + b.text %>
          <% end %>
        <%= f.fields_for @search_option do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.label 'Only private users' %>
                  <%= ff.check_box(:only_profiles, id: 'only-profiles') %>
                <%= ff.label 'Only companies' %>
                  <%= ff.check_box(:only_groups, id: 'only-profiles') %>
              <%= ff.label 'Cities' %>
                <%= ff.text_area :cities, size: "80x10", placeholder: '' %>
        <% end %>
            <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-accept' %>
    <% end %>
```

controller

```
def edit
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    if !@search.users.exists?(current_user.id)
      redirect_to tasks_path
    else
      @search_option = @search.search_options.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi - there's not quite enough information for me to understand what you are trying to do. Can you please add a bit more from your form? What is this a form for (user ? or search?) that will help us to help you figure out what you need to pass to `fields_for`

Comment: @TarynEast I've just added my current code.

Comment: Cool... so when you run that code. What do you actually observe? What do you expect to observe instead? Also OOC why do you want just one search-option when your search `has_many :search_options` ?

Comment: @TarynEast Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Ok, Users can search for different things. Example: User(1) searches for eggs and milk, User(2) searches for eggs and bread, but first one needs results from London and second one from Denver. What we have here: Users - 2, Searches - 3, SearchOptions - 4. I want to show for each user only his option for 'eggs' search. Am I clear? And when I run this code I see exactly what I need, but by me it's not right way to do it.

Comment: Ok, then I think you've misunderstood `has_many`... think of it like this... if any specific, individual user has only one search-option going at a time, then you should declare that a User `has_one :search_option` - which will solve all our problems for you instantly :D Use `has_many` only if a specific individual user has lots of search-options at once... which isn't what you're describing to me :)
Don't worry what another individual user has... they have only one search option too.

Comment: @TarynEast But if one user has many Searches then for each of them he has one Search Option. So there are many search options for one user, or I'm wrong?

Comment: oops, yes that was a mistake/misunderstanding on my part. Hmmm. I think you will need to treat `@search_option` as though there is more than one... even though there will only ever be one shown to the user for a given search? ie it's an array that just happens to always have just one `SearchOption` in it so in the form use: `f.fields_for [@search_option]`

Comment: In matter of fact I should leave my code as it is)

Comment: :) if that is working for you :)